# Office Add-In Browser Sandbox

Tags: javascript, windows, browser, outlook-addin, office-addins

Hi I have noticed that my outlook addin task pane uses internet explorer. 
I know this because when i disable active scripting in internet explorer, the addin javascript does not run. 
Is there a way to change the default browser used by the desktop client? Preferably I would like to use Edge or Chrome

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - no, you can't change the default web browser.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the default browser.